# Where do you put the parentheses to concisely convert a casted object to a primitive type without auto-unboxing?

Tags: java, type-conversion, primitive-types, autoboxing

With autounboxing, this statement will automatically work:

```
int myPrimitive = (Integer) doIt();
```

But if I want to explicitly convert from an `Integer` to an `int` here in a single line, where do I have to put the parentheses?

Comment: my followups would be "why?  what are you trying to do?" :)

Comment: 'I want to explicitly convert from an Integer to an int here in a single line'. That's what you're doing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either the compiler unboxes the Integer for you, or you do it yourself - this cannot be avoided.

So you need to either do

```
int myPrimitive = ((Integer) doIt()).intValue();
```

or more simply, change `doIt()` to return an `int` since you seem to want to deal with `int`s rather than (null-able) `Integer`s.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this :

```
int myPrimitive = (int) (Integer) doIt();
```

But as you said, **auto-unboxing will get that for you**.

A **bad** example to show that chain casts work (**don't ever use this code**) :

```
Map notReallyAMap = (Map) (Object) new String();
```

The thing with chain casts, is that wherever you use it, either the cast is legit, and you can remove intermediaries; or the cast will simply cause a `ClassCastException`. So **you should never use it**.

Comment: A cast from an Integer to an int *IS* a case of auto-unboxing. Integer.intValue() method will do an explicit unboxing. But I do agree with one thing : **Chain cast = don't ever use this!** (+1 for that)

Comment: @Eric-Karl, It is an unboxing I agree, but not really an automatic one.

Comment: [Here is a document](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/jsr/tiger/autoboxing.html) about autoboxing, which tells that explicit cast/conversion is called boxing whereas autoboxing would be automatically done.